# Django UniqueConstraint

Tags: python, django, unique-constraint

### Context

I have the models `AppVersion`, `App` & `DeployApp`. In the `AppVersion`  model users can upload APK files to the filesystem. I am using a `pre_save` signal to prevent uploading APK files with the same `version_code` for a specific `App` like this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=AppVersion)
def prevent_duplicate_version_code(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    qs = AppVersion.objects.filter(app_uuid=instance.app_uuid, version_code=instance.version_code)
    if qs.exists():
        raise FileExistsError("Version code has to be unique for a specific app")
```

This signal does what I want, except it also raises the error when I am trying to create an object in the bridge-table `DeployApp`.

### Models

```
# models.py

class App(models.Model):
    app_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class AppVersion(models.Model):
    app_version_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    app_uuid = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app_versions')
    app_version_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    source = models.FileField(upload_to=get_app_path, storage=AppVersionSystemStorage()) 


class DeployApp(models.Model):
    deploy_app_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    app_version = models.ForeignKey(AppVersion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_group = models.ForeignKey(DeviceGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_date = UnixDateTimeField()
```

My guess is that when creating an object of `DeployApp` the related `AppVersion` is also saved and thus the `pre_save` signal is called and raises the Exception.

I also tried to override the `save()` method for the `AppVersion` model but the results are the same.

How do I make sure that the Exception only happens upon creating a new `AppVersion` instance and does not happen when adding or editing a `DeployApp` instance?

Comment: why not https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together unique_together unique_together = ['app_uuid', 'app_version_name']?

Comment: no, the related model isn't saved if it already exists and all you're doing is creating a `DeployApp` object. That's not possible. There must be something in your code that explicitly saves a `AppVersion` object.

Comment: @BearBrown `unique_together` will soon become obsolete. Have a look at [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Solved it thanks to Bear Brown his suggestion. I removed the signal and added `UniqueConstraint` to the `AppVersion` model like this:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'app_version'
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['app_uuid', 'version_code'], name='unique appversion')
    ]
```

Comment: Using UniqueConstraint() in Models, I am getting this issue :  (models.W044) SQL Server does not support unique constraints on expressions. Can you please help with this ?