# How to define two Django fields unique in certain conditions

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make Django Model fields unique with two fields(values) in some conditions.

> there's two fields: 'team', 'type'. And I want to make team manager unique

For Example:

```
team=1, type='manager'
team=1, type='manager'
```

-> Not available

```
team=1, type='manager'
team=1, type='member'
team=1, type='member'
team=2, type='manager'
```

-> Available

I think `unique_together('team', 'type')` won't work properly with this situation.

How can I make this with Django Model?

Here's my model below:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='member')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_models'
```

Comment: Please share your model

Comment: I added model.py code thx :-)

Comment: welcome, have you added `unique_together('team', 'type')` in Meta ?

Comment: you need to define another table(like **TypeOfUser**) which ref needs to give with ` type ` so only those ref. accepted which exist on **TypeOfUser** so that on will work with `unique_together('team', 'type')`

Comment: I want to make unique only if type=='manager'. Does `unique_together('team', 'type')` works?

Answer (score 1):

I think, You need to use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.fields) for your application which work perfect in kind of situation.

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='member')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_models'
        constraints = [
             models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['team', 'type'], name='unique_team')
        ]
```

you can also refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024059/django-uniqueconstraint) for more understanding. and let me know if following solution will work.

Comment: I want to make unique only if type=='manager'. type=="member" can be duplicate. I think UniqueConstraint is not appreciate for my app :-(

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is a deprecation warning in the documentation (based on 3.2 docs) for `unique_together`, I think it's worth showing that this can be done using UniqueConstraint. I believe that the key missing ingredient from the previous answer is the use of [UniqueConstraint.condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.condition), like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q, UniqueConstraint

class myModel(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='member')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_models'
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['team', 'type'],
                name='unique_team',
                condition=Q(type='manager')
            )
        ]
```